# Handsontable is loosing bahaviour after updateSettings() method

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a problem.
Handsontable work fine with initial data object, but I need to add some extra logic like:
colous for rows and columns, change the markup of table headers.
The good way described in documentation is to use core.updateSettings() and provide my logic in that way.
But after this it ruins my table - sorting start to nor working with some columns, and checkbox field isn't reactive to the keyboard anymore.
Maybe there's any other method I should use intead of updateSettings() ?

I am using v.12

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8ycq5jp/):

```
const hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: [
    [true, 'Model 3', 'BlueStar', 'USA', '★★★★'],
    [true, 'Model S', 'WhiteStar', 'USA', '★★★★★'],
    [true, 'iMiEV', '', 'Japan', '★★'],
    [false, 'Focus EV', '', 'USA', '★★'],
    [false, 'iMiEV Sport', '', 'Japan', '★★'],
    [false, 'Roadster', 'DarkStar', 'USA', '★★★★★'],
    [false, 'e-Golf','', 'Germany', '★★']
  ],
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
  columnSorting: true,
  columns: getColumns(),
  afterColumnSort() {
  const columns = hot.getSettings().columns;
    setTimeout(() => { 
        //hot.updateSettings({ columns: getColumns() })
      hot.updateSettings({ columns })
    }, 1000);
  }
});

function getColumns() {
return [
        { title: 'Available', type: 'checkbox'},
    { title: 'Model' },
    { title: 'Code name' },
    { title: 'Country of origin' },
    { title: 'Rank' },
  ]
}

const baseSettingsToUpdate = {
    cells: (row, col, prop) => {
     const cellProperties = {};
     cellProperties.renderer = (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) => {
     td.innerHtml  = value;
     }
     return cellProperties;
   }
}
hot.updateSettings(baseSettingsToUpdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
const baseSettingsToUpdate = {
    cells: (row, col, prop) => {
     const cellProperties = {};
     cellProperties.renderer = (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) => {
     td.innerHtml  = value;
     }
     return cellProperties;
   }
}
hot.updateSettings(baseSettingsToUpdate)
```

Have you tried this?:

```
const baseSettingsToUpdate = {
   contextMenu: true,
   colHeaders: true,
   fixedRowsTop: 2
}
hot.updateSettings(baseSettingsToUpdate)
```

I am able to sort and update the columns. I am also able to check/uncheck boxes using enter and space keys.

Comment: Thank you but the problem comes up with the "cells" property which - as I presume - rerender and reset the renderers for each column.

Comment: Hey Marcin, try `innerHTML` instead of `innerHtml` in the `38` line in your demo.

Comment: @ABudnik it fixes the sort behavior but changes the checkboxes input to their plain values like "true/fasle".

Comment: Based on your `cells` method that was the intention as you pass a default cell renderer to all of the cells. If the requirement is different you should post the details. Each cell has to have some sort of a renderer, in this case you overwrite a renderer previously set for all of the cells in the table.